# $\mathbb R$ vs. $\omega+\omega$

Tags: set-theory

> 1. Show that there is a subset of $\mathbb R$ which is order-isomorphic to $\omega+\omega$.
> 2. Show that all axioms of ZF except the scheme of Replacement hold in $V_{\omega+\omega}$.

1. How about $\{n/(n+1)\mid n\in\mathbb N\} \cup \mathbb N$? My idea is to associate $\{1/2, 2/3, \ldots\}$ with $\{\emptyset, \emptyset^+, \ldots\}$ and $\{1,2,\ldots\}$ with $\{\omega, \omega+1, \ldots\}$, does that work?
2. I'm confused, how can any ZF axiom not hold for any $V_\alpha$? I thought the von-Neumann hierarchy described the universe of ZF sets.

Comment: 1. That works. 2. To clarify that, let's note that the last sentence isn't true: for example, in $V_{\omega+1}$ axiom of power set doesn't hold, because $\omega$ is a set in $V_{\omega+1}$, but it's power set doesn't exist _in $V_{\omega+1}$_.

Comment: These are two *entirely* different questions. The first one has been answered several times before.

Comment: True. I opened an [extra question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687560/which-zf-axioms-are-satisfied-in-v-omega-omega).

Comment: Alternatively for #1, $\; \{1 - \frac{1}{n} \mid n\in\mathbb N\} \; \cup \; \{2 - \frac{1}{n} \mid n\in\mathbb N\}.\;$ Note this gives you room for more additive copies of $\omega,$ should you need examples for them.

Comment: Re 2.: For any $\alpha$, $V_{\alpha+1}$ is not closed under pairing, as pairing raises rank.

Comment: My favorite embedding of $\omega+\omega$ into $\Bbb R$ is the set of decimals in $[0,1)$ whose decimal expansions consist only of finitely many $1$s and at most one $0$. The map is $\omega a+b\mapsto{}$$0.\underbrace{11\dots11}_{a~\rm1s}0\underbrace{11\dots11}_{b~\rm1s}$.

Comment: (The set is closed in $[0,1)$ if you consider it to be in binary. The description becomes "the numbers in $[0,1)$ whose binary expansions have at most one $0$.")

Comment: $V_0 = \emptyset$ violates the axiom of infinity. Interestingly at least in the version of the axioms [found in the English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) that's apparently the only axiom that's violated, as all others assume the existence of some set. Note that the version found in the German Wikipedia contains the axiom of existence of the empty set, which would also be violated by $V_0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your proposed example works.  Remember that an order isomorphism is just a bijection that preserves order, i.e. a strictly increasing bijection.
2. Certainly the axioms hold in $\bigcup_\alpha V_\alpha$ (taking the union over all ordinals).  Some axioms assert the *existence* of something.  If the thing whose existence is asserted is not in $V_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$, then $V_\alpha$ does not satisfy the axioms.  For example, in $V_{\omega+1}$ the ordinal $\omega$ has no successor.

Comment: $\omega$ does not exist in $V_{\omega}$, only in $V_{\omega+1}$ -- and _there_ it has no successor.

Comment: @HenningMakholm : Indeed.  Sometimes I should be a bit more patient. $\qquad$

Comment: "If the thing whose existence is asserted is not in $V_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$, then $V_\alpha$ does not satisfy the axioms." This is not quite obvious. It is true if the existential statement is $\Sigma_1$, but fails in general. What you need is that no set in $V_\alpha$ witnesses *in* $V_\alpha$ the existential statement. Certainly a set that witnesses something in $V_\alpha$ may fail to witness it in $V$.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1. we have the following fact:

For every countable ordinal $\alpha$ there is a subset $X \subseteq \mathbb Q$ such that $(\alpha, \in)$ and $(X, <)$ are isomorphic, where $<$ is the usual strict order on $\mathbb Q$ restricted to $X$.

Proof. Consider $Y = \alpha \times \mathbb Q$ and let $\prec$ be the strict lexicographical order on $Y$. So, for any $(\beta, q), (\gamma, r) \in Y$ we have $(\beta, q) \prec (\gamma, r)$ iff $\beta \in \gamma$ or [$\beta = \gamma$ and $q < r$]. Now $Y$ is a countable, dense linear order without endpoints and thus there is an isomporphism $\pi \colon (Y, \prec) \to (\mathbb Q, <)$. Let $\rho \colon (\alpha, \in) \to (Y, \prec), \beta \mapsto (\beta,0)$ be the "natural embedding". Then $\pi \circ \rho \colon (\alpha, \in) \to \pi \circ \rho " \alpha$ is an isomorphism from $(\alpha, \in)$ to a suborder of $(\mathbb Q, <)$.

Usually the above result is proved by induction on $\alpha$, but recently it occurred to me, that Cantor's characterization of countable, dense linear orders without endpoints allowed for a shorter proof (provided that Cantor's result is known by the reader).

Answer (score 1):

In general $V_{\alpha}$ does not satisfy ZF, and if we could prove from ZF that some $V_{\alpha}$ satisfies ZF then by Godel's First Incompleteness Theorem  we could prove $1=0$ from ZF.

For brevity let $a=\omega +\omega$  and $X=V_a.$ Assume $X$ satisfies ZF. Then we can prove (1).$a=a^X\in X.$... (2). $B(b)=(B(b))^X$ for  all $b\in a,$ where $B$ is the Beth function.... (3). $V_b=(V_b)^X$ for  all $b\in a.$ But then $X$ satisfies $\;\forall b\in a\;\exists ! c\; (c=V_b),\;$ which is an instance of Replacement, so $X$ satisfies $\;\exists d \;\forall b\in a \;(V_b\in d).$ But then $X$ satisfies$\;\exists d\; (\cup d\supset V) .$

Remark:Whether any of (1),(2),(3) actually does hold in ZF is not needed to show that $X$ does not satisfy ZF.

In order for any $V_a$ to satisfy all of ZF it is sufficient that $a$ is a strongly inaccessible cardinal. If ZF is consistent then neither ZF nor ZFC can prove that such a cardinal exists.

Comment: I once read that the "universe" of Russell and Whitehead's Principia Mathematica is equivalent,  in modern terminology, to $V_{\omega+\omega}$

Comment: You are wrong about the last part. If there are $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha$ models $\operatorname{ZFC}$, then the least such $\alpha$ has cofinality $\omega$. Joel Hamkins named these ordinals "worldly cardinals".

Comment: I have amended  my answer to remove "necesssary" from the 2nd last sentence.