# Which ZF axioms are satisfied in $V_{\omega+\omega}$?

Tags: set-theory

Promoted to a separate question from [$\mathbb R$ vs. $\omega+\omega$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687484/mathbb-r-vs-omega-omega).

> Show that all axioms of ZF except the scheme of Replacement hold in $V_{\omega+\omega}$.

1. Extension: Holds for all subsets of the universe.
2. Separation: $x\in V_{\omega+\omega}$ means $x\in V_{\omega+\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$. But then also $y\in V_{\omega+\alpha}$ for any $y\subseteq x$, ie $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is closed under subsets. Thus Separation holds.
3. Empty set: $\emptyset \in V_{\omega+\omega}$.
4. Pairs: For $x,y\in V_{\omega+\omega}$ we have $x,y\in V_{\omega+\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$. Then $\{x,y\}\in V_{\omega+\alpha+1}$.
5. Union: Similarly $x\cup y \in V_{\omega+\alpha}$.
6. Power-set: $V_{\omega+\alpha}$ is closed under subsets, so for $x\in V_{\omega+\alpha}$ we have $\mathcal Px\in V_{\omega+\alpha+1}$.
7. Infinity: $\omega\in V_{\omega+\omega}$ should be true? Does $\alpha\subseteq V_{\alpha}$ hold in general?
8. Foundation: Holds for all subsets of the universe.
9. Replacement: Apparently doesn't hold but why not? Which function breaks it?

Comment: Is $\omega + \omega$ a set in $V_{\omega + \omega}$? Can you make it using replacement?

Comment: Note that you have the wrong axiom of union. It should not just say that $x\cup y$ exists, but that $\bigcup\limits_{x\in A} x$ exists whenever $A$ is a set.

Comment: Note that for infinite $\alpha$ it is indeed true that $\alpha \subseteq V_\alpha$. Morever, for all $\beta < \alpha$ we have $\alpha \not \subseteq V_\beta$. This can be proved be a simply induction.

Comment: Replacement fails in $V_{\omega+\omega}$ if all the other axioms are satisfied. Otherwise $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is a model of ZF and ZF proves its own consistency.